# JAVA Eclipselink query

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to write a JPA query that has 3 conditional where statements. But I don't seem to get the syntax correct.

```
try {
    Query findCustomerQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE " +
            "CASE " +
            "WHEN :customerNumber is not null THEN (c.customerNumber = :customerNumber)" +
            "WHEN :customerName is not null THEN (c.name = :customerName) " +
            "WHEN :customerFirstname is not NULL THEN (c.firstName = :customerFirstname) ELSE (c.customerNumber = 0) END");

    findCustomerQuery.setParameter("customerNumber",customerNumber);
    findCustomerQuery.setParameter("customerName", customerName);
    findCustomerQuery.setParameter("customerFirstname", customerFirstname);
    return (Customer) findCustomerQuery.getSingleResult();

}finally {
    entityManager.close();
}
```

Comment: WHERE CASE? CASE is used in SELECT not WHERE

Answer (score 0):

It is convenient to use the JPA [Criteria API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html) for these cases.

Here is an example for your case:

```
// get a query builder
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
// build query for entity
CriteriaQuery<Customer> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery( Customer.class );
// set FROM entity
Root<Customer> tags = criteriaQuery.from( Customer.class );
// get a basic predicate
Predicate p = builder.and();
// add WHERE conditions properly
if (customerNumber != null) {
    Predicate conditionPredicate = builder.and(
            builder.equal( tags.get("customerNumber"), customerNumber )
    );
    p = builder.and(p, conditionPredicate);
}
// do the same for customerName and customerFirstName
if (customerName != null) {
    Predicate conditionPredicate = builder.and(
            builder.equal( tags.get("customerName"), customerName )
    );
    p = builder.and(p, conditionPredicate);
}
if (customerFirstName != null) {
    Predicate conditionPredicate = builder.and(
            builder.equal( tags.get("customerFirstName"), customerFirstName )
    );
    p = builder.and(p, conditionPredicate);
}

// set predicate to query
criteriaQuery.where( p );

// call query and get results
TypedQuery<Customer> q = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Customer> o = q.getResultList();
```

Here are [more examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html#gjivs) if you need